# Calulating mean in Excel conditional on available data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let's say I've got four columns in Excel :  A,B,C,D.

I know I can do :

```
=average(A,B,C,D)
```

But there may be instances where data is unavailable for one or more columns.

How can I tell Excel *"Calculate the average only when data is available for two or more columns"*.

e.g.

- A=1,B=2,C=-,D=4 would be ok
- A=1,B=-,C=-,D=4 would be ok
- A=1,B=-,C=-,D=- would ***not*** be ok

UPDATE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use count():

```
=IF(COUNT(A1:D1)>1,AVERAGE(A1:D1),"")
```

To deal with the errors:

```
=IF(AGGREGATE(2,6,O9:S9)>1,AGGREGATE(1,6,O9:S9),"")
```

Comment: I like your thinking, except I still get `#VALUE!` as a result instead of the average of the remaining columns.

Comment: What is the exact formula you are using?

Comment: `=IF(COUNT(O9:S9)>1,AVERAGE(O9:S9))`

Comment: Are there errors in that range?

Comment: I have updated my original post with a screenshot.  The last column is the average column, the other 5 columns are the data columns.

Comment: This is information that would have been nice to have before I wasted my time.

Comment: ?!? I was very clear originally.  I even gave examples where data was missing in my original post  !!

Comment: I did say "there may be instances where data is unavailable "

Comment: But you did not say the data could have errors, only missing numbers.

Comment: Please see edit.